# Django migrations not working properly in ecs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I have a django application on ecs. I push the code to github along with the migrations files. I have a script that runs the migrate command when I deploy. I can create a superuser but when I try to login to admin panel I get relation user_user does not exist error, but when I connect to the RDS directly form my local system I can login, but not from the domain which is attached to the elb

Comment: a such "user_user" table does not exist by default on Django. Can you explain and give more details about your setup and your problem ? What is your database ? Can you show in particular your ECS task definition and your Django settings file (for the database part) ?

Comment: This question severely lacks details. This likely means that your ecs cluster does not connect to the same rds database, but you need to show much more configuration to figure out why.

Comment: Django migrations themselves have no problem or incompatibility with the Amazon ECS service. You need to describe in much more detail exactly what is happening.